# Multiple panel when click on button occurs in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a timer, now I want whenever I click on "Add Timer" button a new panel with same existing panel property appears on the form below to existing panel. How can I do this?

The code I have so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int countdown;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countdown = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(countdown);
        label4.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        ts = ts.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));

        textBox1.Text = ts.TotalSeconds.ToString();
        label4.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        if (ts.TotalSeconds == 0)
        {
            //timer1.Stop();
            label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            MessageBox.Show("Times Up!");
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(button3.Text=="Start")
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            button3.Text = "Reset";
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            button3.Text = "Start";
            timer1.Stop();
            textBox1.Text = "00";
            label4.Text = "00:00:00";
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(button4.Text=="Pause")
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            button4.Text = "Resume";
        }
        else
        {
            button4.Text = "Pause";
            timer1.Start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what *'new panel with same existing panel property'* means?

Comment: i just mean whenever i click on add timer button a new timer exists and work independently

Comment: Put all this code in a UserControl. In your form window you, when user clicks an "Add" button, crete and add that UserControl into a container (Panel?). That's done.

Comment: actually am a fresher and i cant know how to put code in a user control and add into a container can u brief explain it through code

Comment: #Adriano. please write a code to explain

Comment: Code is pretty long. Just add a new item to project, select user control and replicate what you did there. Google for a tutorial, it's more easy with pictures!

Comment: #Adrianoi just need a demo of this. for example if a textbox appear on a form and clicking on a button a new textbox appears always.Can u please write code for this.